# Qt Authentication users with QTcpServer (with username and password)

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I want to write a chat program with login page.

I want to send request from client to server with username and password, then server receives, verifies and then responds to client.

Can anyone please guide me of what QT class should I use or can tell me some ideas of how to access them?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html), you can set up authentication for client with some basic `username:password` pair at the start. As soon as the connection is established, ask or wait for the `username:password` to be sent over to the Server. Verify it. In case of invalid data or timeout, close the connection.

As far as the login page is concerned, you need to host that on the Server and you'll be dealing in HTTP protocol instead of TCP. Take a look at [QHttp](https://github.com/azadkuh/qhttp). That'll get you started.

For Qt, there are other options too. You just have to lay down your requirements and find the one that might fulfill those e.g. [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt).

Comment: @Ra'naMohammadi: Nope! I certainly cannot! You asked for the ideas. Here are the ideas. Now, you need to put some effort and get yourself started. There is loads of information on the internet. Study, practice, and post on SO if you are stuck in some issue. Best of luck! Happy coding! :)

Comment: :)) ok,
Thank you very much